# Logical operators "<=" inside SUMIFS function

Tags: excel-formula

I have this equation that I am trying to replace the `4/30/2018` with `EOMONTH` function

```
 =SUMIFS('RawDataAdwords - Daily'!$N$2:$N$1000,'RawDataAdwords - Daily'!$A$2:$A$1000,">="&$A2,'RawDataAdwords - Daily'!$A$2:$A$1000,"<=4/30/2018",'RawDataAdwords - Daily'!$C$2:$C$1000,"*Display")
```

Here is my attempt and I don't know how to actually get the new nested function to work

```
=SUMIFS('RawDataAdwords - Daily'!$N$2:$N$1000,'RawDataAdwords - Daily'!$A$2:$A$1000,">="&$A2,'RawDataAdwords - Daily'!$A$2:$A$1000,"<=EOMONTH(I24,)",'RawDataAdwords - Daily'!$C$2:$C$1000,"*Display")
```

I know the problem is how I am combining the logical operators and the `EOMONTH` function so I could use some input on what to do. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with: "<="&EOMONTH(I24,0)